# VaadinWebSecurity refresh InMemoryUserDetailsManager

Tags: spring-security, vaadin, vaadinwebsecurity, inmemoryuserdetailsmanager

I made a Vaadin app which uses the `VaadinWebSecurity`.

```
@Bean
@Override
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
  // retrieve users from database and insert by a loop
  // new users are added while the app is running
  UserDetails user = User.withUsername("user")
          .password("{noop}userpass")
          .roles("USER")
          .build();

  return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
}
```

When I add a new user, the created user will only recognized after the app get's restarted.

How can I update / refresh the users in the `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` during runtime?

Comment: Create your own UDM, that reads the data from a mutable place. The IM one is meant to be constant.